# Como criptografar um código PHP?

Tags: php

Criei um sistema usando o padrão MVC (model-view-controller), em PHP e banco de dados MySQL, e gostaria de criptografar o código, pelo menos as principais partes, antes de sair do meu computador, para evitar que seja copiado e utilizado sem a minha autorização.

Answer (score 0):

O PHP dispõem do [Blenc - BLowfish ENCoder for PHP source scripts](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.blenc.php) para criptografia o código fonte.

Você vai precisar de acesso ao servidor para configurar ele. Mas fique atento que seu código ainda assim pode ser descriptografado. A partir do momento em que você detecta a invasão no seu servidor, você ganha um tempo para recompilar eu sistema com novas chaves e senhas.